# Error: unknown filesystem. Grub rescue. Insmod normal not working

Tags: boot, grub2, live-cd

I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and after a reboot I got Error:unknown filesystem. Grub rescue.
I have tried :

```
set root=(hd0,6)
set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
```

But I get an error at the last one I get this error: `Error: no such partition`.

I also tried to update grub from a live cd but when I enter: `sudo mount /dev/sda5/mnt` i get this:

`-mount: can't find /dev/sda5/mnt in etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`.

Can someone help?

Comment: plz upload the gparted screenshot.

Comment: `sudo mount /dev/sda5/mnt` this was a wrong command,the right one was `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt`

Answer (score 1):

First, `sudo mount /dev/sda5/mnt` won't do anything because `/dev/sda*` is a block device and doesn't have a folder in it because...it isn't a folder.

This happened to me.  Boot to the LiveCD again and use:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

to figure out which drive to choose (hopefully you know what size it was).  Then set your grub to the correct `root()` drive.

To mount it in the LiveCD use

```
cd ~ && mkdir systmp && sudo mount /dev/*DISK* systmp
```

Report back with results, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Run LiveCD and give us results:

```
sudo apt-get install parted; sudo parted --list
```

Download Boot info script ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/ ) and paste the result.

You can also give us a screenshot from GParted.

And 2 questions: which partition table are you using and which type is your root partition (for example ext4, ext3, brtfs etc.)?

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry I took so long for me to reply. The problem was that I did not pay enough attention while I was trying to mount the boot partition. My partition is sdab5, not sda. Thanks all for your help!